# How to toggle a @State variable from App Delegate for the GoogleSignIn framework?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, google-signin, combine

I'm using the GoogleSignIn framework in `AppDelegate` of my SwiftUI app.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {

      if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
      }

      guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
      let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                        accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential){ (res, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            else{
                print("User:" + (res?.user.email)!)
                // where I've tried toggling isPresentingSignIn
            }
        }
    }
```

The sign in is initiated from a `SignInView` sheet that is presented over my `Home` view before the user signs in for the first time. I want to dismiss `SignInView` once the sign in completes without error.

```
struct Home: View {

    @State var isPresentingSignIn = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This Is The Home View") 
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSignIn, content: {
            SignInView()
        })
    }
}
```

The sign in is working great, but I don't know how to dismiss my SignInView once authentication is successful. I've tried toggling `isPresentingSignIn` from the sign in function in `AppDelegate` but it doesn't seem like I have access to `isPresentingSignIn` outside of the body of `Home`.

How can I dismiss `SignInView` after a successful authentication?

Answer (score -1):

`@State` can't be set outside the body. But `ObservableObject` can be. There are other options, but that's the closest to what you are trying to do.